# flutter android error Gradle during the build time?

Tags: android, flutter

Specifically, it mentions that it could not run a phased build action due to a missing initialization script

```
[{
    "resource": "/Users/datart-6/ap_test/android/build.gradle",
    "owner": "_generated_diagnostic_collection_name_#4",
    "code": "0",
    "severity": 8,
    "message": "Could not run phased build action using connection to Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.5-all.zip'.\nThe specified initialization script '/var/folders/gz/sw9vl68x68ncv7x8hyvxbm3w0000gn/T/d146c9752a26f79b52047fb6dc6ed385d064e120494f96f08ca63a317c41f94c.gradle' does not exist.",
    "source": "Java",
    "startLineNumber": 1,
    "startColumn": 1,
    "endLineNumber": 1,
    "endColumn": 1
}] this is the error message??
```